Bibliography request for sequential decision making with past decisions affecting future costs
I am working on a problem of N discrete stages in which there are M discrete states to be in at each step. Because of continuity constraints on the system, deciding to be at State i in Stage N affects the costs associated to different future actions (but not the possible actions, which remain unchanged).
For example, consider two paths $P_1 = 1 \rightarrow  2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4$ and $P_2 = 1 \rightarrow  1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4$, then $3 \rightarrow 4$ has different costs in each case, because the past is different.
I would like to know how this kind of problems are called in the literature so I can read about it, any particular suggestions are welcomed.
